# Flash Player object to Mobile

Tags: php, html, flash, mobile, video

I am working with an open API on an adult website. They allow you to pull videos that they offer, which is great, but they are returned as flash objects, similar to below:

```
<object height="344" width="434">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="movie" value="http://embed.redtube.com/player/?id=260891&style=redtube">
    <param name="FlashVars" value="id=260891&style=redtube&autostart=true">
    <embed src="http://embed.redtube.com/player/?id=260891&style=redtube" 
        allowfullscreen="true" 
        AllowScriptAccess="always" 
        flashvars="autostart=true" 
        pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        height="344" width="434" />
</object>
```

This is all well and good, I can edit this code for different params and put it in my website and everything works fine. However, because it is a flash player, none of the videos will play on any sort of mobile device.

I have tried a few different creative solutions to no avail, could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Many video sites have a mobile version that allows videos to be played on iPhone etc. and so probably will have non-flash embeds or links to the streaming video that you can scrape. That's probably your best bet. This is definitely against the web site's terms of service, though, and the site is probably designed specifically to make what you're trying to do difficult, so if you do find a way to make it work, it probably won't work for long.

Answer (score 0):

Redtube has it ups and downs

Main up is their API which saves you from storing the URLs or video IDs with it's information on your own machine.

The largest and main down is their lack of support for mobile embedded videos, if you navigate to a mobile page you'll see the "embed" button is no longer present, because they limit access to their mobile content to their own domain only.

So it's pretty much having an external API but no mobile support vs. Storing the IDs + Other relevant info on your host/machine(From other tubes) but their embedded video provides some support to mobile devices (usually by opening the mobile's player and playing an mp4).

edit:

You can manually embed an iFrame if the client is mobile and play around with it's position so it's showing the client RedTube's mobile player.